# COUNT() domain names in emails based on the current month returning all records

Tags: mysql

I have a query as such

```
SELECT right(accounts.username, length(accounts.username)-
        INSTR(accounts.username, '@')) domain, 
        COUNT(*) email_count 
FROM tickets 
    LEFT JOIN accounts ON tickets.user = accounts.ID 
WHERE (tickets.timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))) 
GROUP BY domain 
ORDER BY email_count DESC
```

I have a `ticket` table that I LEFT JOIN to associate the user `accounts` of that ticket to get the `email(username)` of that user.

I am trying to count the users `email` and how many tickets appear with a particular domain name of that user for the current `MONTH`. Problem is that it is ignoring the `MONTH` and returning all records that match.

**For instance**

```
yahoo.com        3,356
gmail.com        1,345
```

If I do a search for all records I get these numbers, but it should be much lower if it is just for the month. I am using UNIX timestamps for this.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Modified for only current month:**

```
SELECT 
RIGHT(accounts.username, length(accounts.username)-INSTR(accounts.username, '@')) AS domain, COUNT(1) AS email_count 
FROM tickets 
LEFT JOIN accounts ON tickets.user = accounts.ID 
WHERE
YEAR(tickets.timestamp) = YEAR(NOW())
AND MONTH(tickets.timestamp) = MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY domain
ORDER BY email_count DESC
```

Comment: I need just the current month, I do not need to group by months

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())))` expression:

1. `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())` => 1
2. `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1)` => this should result either in an error (1292 incorrect datetime value) or warning of the same and 0 as a result, depending on whether strict sql mode is enabled.

Since you wrote the query returns all records, strict sql mode must be turned off, which can cause issues like this. It would have been easier to get a straight error message.

If you want to return records from the current month, then you can use the following expression, where I used year() and month() functions to get current year and month and concatenated 1 to it to get the 1st day of the month:

```
tickets.timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-',MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()),'-','1')
```

Comment: I use this same expression for other reports I have and it works fine with those, not sure why it wouldn't work with this one.

Comment: @CesarBielich no clue either, but the expression you created there is simply wrong and does not work anywhere, unless you want to return a 0.

Answer (score 0):

> `WHERE tickets.timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))`

This expression probably does not do what you think. `MONTH()` returns the number of the month (1 to 12), while you want the beginning of the current month.

You can use the following expression to compute the beginning of the month:

```
date_format(current_date(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

In your condition:

```
where tickets.timestamp >= unix_timestamp(date_format(current_date(), '%Y-%m-01'))
```